# Selecting a YouTube video using just the keyboard on search page

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, youtube, web

I have a system where I mainly want to use the keyboard for navigating and I can get around half-decent however when I hit the **Tab button repeatedly** on the search results page it highlights the three dot button which is for options (add to queue for example). How can you highlight the video itself and cycle through them using just the keys? The only chrome-based browser I can do this in is using Vivaldi's spatial navigation keys (shift+up,left,down,right) which outlines using an orange box each title or link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using chrome on win10.  if you press tab enough times, it will eventually cycle through all the "related searches" under the search box.  tab won't highlight the video's picture but it will cycle through the video, three dots, and content creator for each video (in that order).  the bottom left corner of the browser will show you what link is currently highlighted.

Comment: You know something, its works on Chrome but not Vivaldi. I assumed since they both used chromium that the results would be the same but they weren't. I'll check Edge and Opera next.